# Programatically get parent ids of products of array

Tags: magento-1.9, product, array

I am working on module and want to fetch parent product ids of child product. If it exists. I am using following line of codes,

```
$parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product_id);
```

This line of code is work for single product and give me details array of parent id.

I want above line works for array of products:

```
$productArraya = array('12','15','18','40');
```

I put this array of products in to above line but not work.

Comment: Have you tried 

$productArray = array('1','15','25','35','42');
      $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productArray);
         
?

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Pls try 

$productArray = array('1','15','25','35','42');
   $productArray = implode(',',$productArray);
   $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productArray);

Answer (score 2):

If you check class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable

There is a function

```
public function getParentIdsByChild($childId)
{
    $parentIds = array();

    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable(), array('product_id', 'parent_id'))
        ->where('product_id IN(?)', $childId);
    foreach ($this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select) as $row) {
        $parentIds[] = $row['parent_id'];
    }

    return $parentIds;
}
```

So it might be some issue how you are passing array in function.

Comment: I dont want use foreach loop.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: How can i use this function, it give me error of Call to undefined method _getReadAdapter()

Comment: This is the source code for the function you're already calling @Mathew

Comment: @AkhileshPatel it expects a comma delimited string rather than an array

Answer (score 1):

Please use bellow code

```
    $childProductIds = array('1','15','25','35','42');
    $childProductId = implode(',',$childProductIds);
     //or
    //$childProductId = "1,15,25,35,42";

    $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($childProductId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop it

```
foreach($productArraya as $product_id)
{
$parentIds[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product_id);

}
print_r($parentIds);
```

Comment: I dont want use foreach loop.

Comment: may i know why ?

Comment: If large amount of products comes in array then loop is working number of times. I want loop work one time only and gives result.